# Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid in asp.net mvc core 3.1 application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried executing the below code in my asp net mvc core 3.1 application. But i am getting an error in data.Data saying : Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid

```
   using (var process = new Process())
{
  process.StartInfo.FileName = @"../InputSource/tools/dotnet-counters.exe";         // relative path. absolute path works too.
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("monitor --process-id {0} System.Runtime", processId);
  process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

  process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, data) =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine(data.Data);
    File.WriteAllText(@"../Output/CounterProcessData.txt", data.Data);
  };
  process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, data) =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine(data.Data);
    File.WriteAllText(@"../Output/CounterProcessData.txt", data.Data);
  };
  Console.WriteLine("starting");
  process.Start();
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  process.BeginOutputReadLine();
  process.BeginErrorReadLine();
  var exited = process.WaitForExit(1000 * 10);     // (optional) wait up to 10 seconds
  Console.WriteLine($"exit {exited}");
}
```

Could you please help?

Comment: So the code you posted works fine, use a debugger to find the bug in dotnet-counters.exe.

Comment: You are writing the SAME output textfile for both ErrorDataReceived and OutputDataReceived. Are the events asynchronous ? When these events come in at about the same time, you will get a file exception...